# Detect if user is signed in in the iTunes store

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes-store

Is there any way to detect from your app (without using any private api) to detect if the iPhone (iOS) user has iTunes Store signed in or not?

Comment: No, there are no Apis for this

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: Well, I am working for a client where when the user enters in the shop screen (for in app purchase item), he wants us to detect if the user is already logged in or not (iTunes Store) and if not, then show a custom alert message (other than standard UIAlertView).

Comment: Can't be done. You are stuck with the standard login. It prevents fraud and tricking the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way for you to detect if the user has signed into their account in the app store.

Is there a particular reason why you are looking for this functionality?  Your app should not worry about this.

Comment: There seem to be some situations where an alert comes up "Sign in to iTunes Store". I'd like to avoid whatever causes that alert when the user isn't signed in.

Comment: @gnasher729 I have the same need. Did you ever come up with a solution?