# Check if User is Logged into iTunes before processing In-app? Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, itunes

I am working on IOS in apps,
I wanted to display the payments page only if the **user logged-in with device iTunes account**. otherwise simply will display a message to login in Itunes to make payments

even IOS is handling while making payments, i just need to check before make payment request

and also need to display some of my pages, only if the user logged into iTunes

thanks in advance

Comment: Just as a note, When you use `StoreKit` to make payments, iOS will ask the user for login details when necessary, you don't have to do anything else (such as validations like this).

Answer (score 2):

you can check if user logged in to icloud account using this..

```
func isICloudContainerAvailable()->Bool {
    if let currentToken = NSFileManager.defaultManager().ubiquityIdentityToken {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

there is no way to check is user signed in the itunes store.
see this answer about itunes store login. hope it may help understanding.
[Detect if user is signed in in the iTunes store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978794/detect-if-user-is-signed-in-in-the-itunes-store)

Comment: In I-Phone 5S  i can see tow different logins for both icloud and itunes