# Check if user is signed into iTunes Store

Tags: ios, react-native

I have in app purchases enabled in my app, and there's some functionality i would like to incorporate.

If a user is reinstalling the app, and on a previous install made non-consumable in app purchases, i would like to attempt to restore the functionality that the user has previously paid for.

I'm currently able to query if the user has previously purchased any extra content. However, if the user is not logged into the iTunes store, they will be greeted with an iTunes login. Although very few users wont be logged in, i really wouldn't want that to happen – my app asking the user to log into the iTunes Store immediately on the first launch would look really fishy.

Ideally i would only attempt to check the previous purchases if the user is already logged into iTunes, and i'm able to check the previous purchases silently.

Is this possible in iOS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if user is signed in in the iTunes store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978794/detect-if-user-is-signed-in-in-the-itunes-store)

Comment: It's from almost 4 years ago. Only answer is "No", with 0 upvotes, hoping something's changed in that time.